# How to get hostname of clients connect to async UDP server by asio library?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am writing an async UDP server by using asio library. I want to get the hostnames of those UDP clients which connect to my server. How could I do this? Also, is it possible to get the hostname of UDP client without reverse-DNS resolving it just like java library guava inetaddress?

```
class udp_server
{
asio::ip::udp::socket socket;
asio::ip::udp::endpoint remote_endpoint;
std::array<std::uint8_t,16384> buffer;
sqlite::sqlite db;
void start()
{
    socket.async_receive_from(asio::buffer(buffer),remote_endpoint,[this](const std::error_code& error,std::size_t bytes)
    {
        start();
    });
}
public:
udp_server(asio::io_service& io_service,unsigned long port,const char* dbpath):socket(io_service,asio::ip::udp::endpoint(asio::ip::udp::v4(),port)),db(dbpath)
{
    start();
}
};
```

How can I get hostname of this remote_endpoint? Thank you! 
Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'connect to a UDP server'. The source address and port of each datagram is available in the datagram.

Comment: ok. How can i get hostname of an ip address?